# There is no projective plane of order $10$.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I need to determine if there is a projective plane of order $10$.   The Bruck-Ryser theorem tells us that if $n \equiv2, 1 \bmod 4$, and there is a projective plane of order $n$, then $n$ is a sum of two squares.

I cannot use this here since $10 = 1 + 3^2$.   I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is known, but I don’t think you’re going to come up with a demonstration of your own. See http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lam305-318.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes),

> The next case N = 10 has been ruled out by massive computer calculations.

See Lam, Clement W. H. ($1991$), "[The Search for a Finite Projective Plane of order $10$](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lam/)", American Mathematical Monthly $\mathbf{98}$ $(4): 305–318$.